# Why is a spider object needed in spider.py for scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have seen that in some spider files in the end of class they use

```
class TestSpider(BaseSpider):
   pass


SPIDER = TestSpider()
```

Why do we use `SPIDER = TestSpider()`? I didn't use it, and my spider is working fine.

Comment: likely for future extensibility? ... just a guess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrapy originally used twisted's plugin mechanism to manage spiders and this requires an instance. This was changed in favor of inspecting classes for anything extending BaseSpider & having a name. You will still see instances created in old code, although it is no longer required in any recent scrapy version.

Answer (score 0):

In the case, you should above, `SPIDER = BaseSpider()` is likely to work. As well as perhaps leaving the file blank if `SPIDER` is defined by default elsewhere. I'm not too familiar with scrapy.